# Google App Engine Python: Error in yaml config file when deploying

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google App Engine, Python37 environment.
I got an error message when trying to deploy a microservice today:
I run the command:

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

Got the error:

```
...
File upload done.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: script field for handler '/.*' 
must be set to 'auto' for runtime python37.
PS C:\path_to_app> gcloud app deploy app.yaml
...
```

My app.yaml is:

```
service: service_name
runtime: python37

handlers:
- url: /.*
script: main.py
```

It looks exactly the same from other microservices that I have deployed recently, just the service name is different. 
I tried to re-deploy a services that is already running and got same error message.
So I double check app.yaml reference document: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref 
But I couldn't find out what is wrong neither why the same yaml file that had worked before doesn't work anymore.

Does anyone know what can be wrong or maybe what can be changed on Google App Engine in the last days?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That page states: "The only accepted value for the script element is *auto*."  You have `script: main.py`

Comment: I tried to change it to auto, didn't work either.

Comment: Seems like I had screwed it up first try with a typo. I tried again to change it to `script: auto` and it worked. Thanks snakecharmerb, you answered my question. It is a beta services and chances like this can happen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the [AppEngine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#handlers_script) for Python 3.7,

> The only accepted value for the **script** element is **auto**

Below is a sample entry from the documentation:

```
handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images

- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

Comment: Thanks Omair. snakecharmedb has also pointed that. This is a beta service and seems like they have changed this week. I already fixed it.

Comment: Did you test this already? does it still use main.py by default of do we need to write a dispach.yaml and/or index.yaml too? The documentation is not clear on this.

Answer (score 3):

The earlier answer from [@Omair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10553701/omair), while correct, is only part of the story. The OP's original question utilizes an App Engine first-generation ("Gen1") runtime app's `app.yaml` configuration file where the routing happens, requiring the `script:` directive in `handlers:`. While that's a **perfectly valid `app.yaml`** for a Gen1 (`go111`, `python` [2.5], `python27`, `php55`) app, it won't work for next generation ("Gen2") apps.

> **NOTE:** Python 2 is only supported by App Engine Gen1 whereas Python 3 is only supported by App Engine Gen2 (Standard or Flex), so [if you migrate from Python 2 to 3, you're also porting from Gen1 to Gen2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3) and need to keep in mind these differences as well. (Unfortunately, this means migrating from `webapp2` to a web framework that handles routing, i.e., Django, Flask, etc.)

App Engine [Gen2 *requires* routing to be done by your framework](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/config-files#updating_appyaml). As a result, all Gen1 `app.yaml` files need to be updated. Use of `handlers:` for your routes must be either removed or changed to `auto` (because it's done by your web framework now). If you have specific app startup instructions, you can provide [an `entrypoint:` directive](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#entrypoint); check out [these examples](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup).

Both `handlers:` and `entrypoint:` are optional. If all script handlers are `auto`, you don't need `handlers:` unless your app is serving static files like client-side JS, CSS, HTML, images, etc., and `entrypoint:` is optional because if you don't specify a server, `gunicorn` is selected (and started) by default. Basically if you take all the defaults and don't serve static files, you can reduce `app.yaml` down to 1 line, like [this one](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/migrate-python2-appengine/blob/master/mod2b-cloudndb/app.yaml). That sample is from a repo I'm working on to help developers upgrade Python 2 App Engine apps to Python 3 who need more help than what's available in the [official migration guide](http://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3).

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when deploying a flask app with a blueprint structure. The solution is to have `main.py` file in the same directory as `app.yaml` file. In the `main.py` file, import the app object e.g `from app import app` (here the first 'app' is the folder containing an **init** file where the flask app instance is created). After doing this, setting script to auto should work fine.