# Can't access my PHP files trough Ajax on the App engine

Tags: php, ajax, google-app-engine, yaml

I have deployed a PHP app on the App engine but all my Ajax calls to PHP files seems to be redirected to my index.php file. Sending me the whole index.php's generated HTML as response.

Accessing the file directly also load the index.php (https://[mybucket].appspot.com/includes/engine/checkFollowStateFirestore.php)

I believe it may come from my App.yaml but i can't find a working answer on internet.

Here is my App.yaml file:

```
runtime: php72

default_expiration: "1s"

handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: css
- url: /vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css
  static_dir: vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css
- url: /js
  static_dir: js
- url: /vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/js
  static_dir: vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/js
- url: /assets/images
  static_dir: assets/images
```

I have tried adding:

```
- url: .*
  script: auto
```

or

```
- url: /includes/engine/*
  script: auto
```

or

```
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

Options such as:

```
- url: /includes/engine/checkFollowStateFirestore.php
  script: includes/engine/checkFollowStateFirestore.php
```

Gives me this error on deployment:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: script field for handler '/includes/engine/checkFollowStateFirestore.php' must be set to 'auto' for runtime php72
```

Using PHP include/require works.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117774/google-app-engine-python-error-in-yaml-config-file-when-deploying) post, could you confirm that your app's main .php file is in the same directory as app.yaml file?